# How to rewrite full content of a file in C

Tags: c, linux

I have text file which uses for ajax source. Every 1 sec browser sends ajax request to read actual data from this file.
Also I have deamon written on C which writes actual data to that file. Look at the following code:

```
static void writeToFile_withLock(const char * file_path, const char * str)
{
    struct flock fl = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET,   0,      0,     0 };
    int fd;
    const char * begin = str;
    const char * const end = begin + strlen(str);

    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    if ((fd = open(file_path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Trying to get lock...\n");
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("got lock\n");

    printf("Try to write %s\n", str); 
    while (begin < end)
    {
        size_t remaining = end - begin;
        ssize_t res = write(fd, begin, remaining);
        if (res >= 0)
        {
            begin += res;
            continue; // Let's send the remaining part of this message
        }
        if (EINTR == errno)
        {
            continue; // It's just a signal, try again
        }
        // It's a real error
        perror("Write to file");
        break;
    }

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;  /* set to unlock same region */

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Unlocked.\n");

    close(fd);

}
```

The problem: If former data was > the new data then old several symbols keeped at the end of the file.

How I can rewrite full file content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `O_TRUNC` flag to open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add O_TRUNC to the open() call...

> **O_TRUNC**
>
> If the file already exists and is a regular file and the open mode
>   allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to
>   length 0.  If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file,  the O_TRUNC
>   flag is ignored.  Otherwise the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options.  Either set the `O_TRUNC` bit of the 2nd parameter of `open` to discard all content when you open the file, or call `ftruncate` when you are finished to discard the content of the file that you do not want.  (Or use `truncate`, but since you already have an open file descriptor, there's no advantage to doing that.)